# Determining the closeness of nodes by their neighbours

Tags: graph-theory, networks

**Background**

I have a directional network that is comprised of two types of nodes, `business_sector` nodes, and `event_type` nodes. Currently there are only edges between `business_sector` nodes and `event_type` nodes and vice versa.

The edges represent a measure of co-occurence between a `business_sector` and an 'event_type' in a dataset I have. For every business and event, there are two edges that represent two related measures of co-occurence. The background to these measures is a little involved so I'll leave it out unless someone thinks it pertinent to the question.

**My Question**

Assuming these measures make sense and provide us a good representation of how related different `business_sectors` are to different `event_types`, is it possible to use this network model to also determine how similar different `business_sectors` are based on the relationship each `business_sector` has with each `event_type`? The business sectors have no edges between them, but share neighbour nodes as all `business_sector` nodes connect to all `event_type` nodes, with varying weighted edges.
Is it possible to produce a measure that might allow us to say `business_sector` a is similar to `business_sector` b because they have a similar connectivity to all the `event_types`.

I may not be using the correct vocabulary here but I hope my description is enough. Any input on possible measures or approaches (I'm using Networkx and Gephi but any input on the issue is very welcome.)

Thank you!

**Note:**

I have attempted to measure this outside of graph theory by making every `business_sector` an observation, and the weight of each sector to each `event_type` a variable and then calculating pairwise cosine distance between each sector, but this doesn't appear to be producing valid results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James, what you have here is a called a bipartite graph.  There are many algorithms and methods for finding structures in this objects when the graphs are sparse, but it sounds like your all-to-all graph is more like a feature matrix than a graph.  You could enforce sparsity by thresholding your weights, but it sounds like that will throw-out valuable information.

I think your approach using a distance metric is more valid than a graph-theoretic one, its just that your choice of metric may not have been the right one.  If the weights themselves are important (not just the angle), and all event types are qualitatively the same, you should use something closer to the Euclidean distance or mean absolute error.

Its likely that a hierarchical clustering will give you interpretable results.

Comment: This is a really good answer. Answers my specific question but adds and provides me anothet direction too. Thanks so much!